# JSON import nested object to relational tables with Talend

Tags: mongodb, talend, jsonpath

I am trying to import data from **MongoDB** to a **relational DB** (SQL Server).

I don't have access to the MongoDB components so I am querying my collection with the mongo java driver, in a tJava component.

I get a:

> List< DBObject >

which I send to a tExtractJSONFields

An object of my collection looks like this:

```css
[
   {
      "_id":{
         "$oid":"1564t8re13e4ter86"
      },
      "object":{
         "shop":"shop1",
         "domain":"Divers",
         "sell":[
            {
               "location":{
                  "zipCode":"58000",
                  "city":"NEVERS"
               },
               "properties":{
                  "description":"ddddd!!!!",
                  "id":"f1re67897116fre87"
               },
               "employee":[
                  {
                     "name":"employee1",
                     "id":"245975"
                  },
                  {
                     "name":"employee2",
                     "id":"458624"
                  }
               ],
               "customer":{
                  "name":"Customer1",
                  "custid":"test_réf"
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   }
]
```

For a sell, I can have several employees. I have an array of employee and I want to store the affected employee in another table. So I would have 2 tables:

```
Sell
oid                |  shop  |  domain  |  zipCode  | ...
1564t8re13e4ter86  |  shop1 |  Divers  |  58000    | ...


Affected employee
employee_id  |  employee_name   |  oid
245975       |  employee1       | 1564t8re13e4ter86
458624       |  employee2       | 1564t8re13e4ter86
```

So I want to loop on the employee array, with a Jsonpath query:

> "$[*].object.sell[0].employee"

The problem is that doing like this, I can't have the object_id. It seems that I can't get an attribute on a parent node if I define my Jsonpath query like this.

I also saw that I can do like in the following link:
http://techpoet.blogspot.ro/2014/06/dealing-with-nested-documents-in.html?utm_content=buffer02d59&utm_medium=social&utm_source=twitter.com&utm_campaign=buffer

But I don't understand when does he get the object_id at the lower levels.

How can I do?

Comment: Hi, it seems to me that Xpath could be a better option since you can have parent node using Xpath (I think it is the dot or double dot for parent). The object ID will be repeated for each row but you will have it.

Comment: Unfortunately, Xpath doesn't work for this JSON. I don't understand why, but I have been trying all the kind of xpath query but without any success...

Answer (score 0):

my tests with JSONPath failed as well but I think this must be a bug in the component because when I query:

$..['$oid'] I'm getting back -> [].

This seems to be the case whenever you try to get a node that's on higher levels than the loop query.